# Getting back Ubuntu's default boot splash

Tags: boot

I am a Gnome user. Just out of curiosity, I installed the package kubuntu-desktop to check out the latest KDE. The package has hijacked and replaced the nice ubuntu boot splash with the blue KDE one. How can I get the original boot splash back ? Which package should I re-install ?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If you want to quickly change it back, `sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth` will give you a list of screens you can choose from.

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me. I installed the gnome desktop, but ended up not liking it. When I uninstalled it, it left the gnome foot logo on the boot and shutdown screens. This got me back the good old ubuntu logo. :)

Comment: This worked temporarily for me. On the next boot kubuntu spalsh screen was back. Maybe it has something to do with the fact that kubuntu splash is in auto mode and the default is in manual mode.

Answer (score 10):

Or simply

```
sudo apt-get remove plymouth-theme-kubuntu-logo
```

If you don't want drop KDE

Answer (score 5):

If you do this, you should be back to normal:

```
sudo apt-get purge kubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-deskop
```

The splash screen is selected via `update-alternatives`, but the above should restore the links too.

Answer (score 5):

Trying out codeMonk's [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/12422/19083) gave me an error after I selected the ubuntu-logo option:

```
update-alternatives: warning: forcing reinstallation of alternative /lib/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/ubuntu-logo.plymouth because link group default.plymouth is broken.
```

Running this command fixed that for me:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo
```

Answer (score -1):

Turning ON/OFF the splash screen on boot is easily changeable via GRUB.

```
sudo vim /etc/default/grub
```

You'll see `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`

1. Remove `splash` from this line
2. Save with `:wq`
3. `sudo update-grub`
4. `sudo reboot now`

Splash screen will no longer appear.

Comment: While editing system files, `sudoedit file` is the preferred way. It chooses vim if available, else falls back to nano

Comment: I believe it simply defaults to the editor specified by the EDITOR environment variable `echo $EDITOR`, which on some systems is vim (or vim.tiny) on others it is nano. You can test this by running `EDITOR=nano sudoedit /etc/default/grub` or `EDITOR=vim sudoedit /etc/default/grub` it chooses the one you specify without making it permanent.